# Navigation Link Pops main view when pushed from side menu

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am using the navigation links with the side menu.

As we can see from the below gif when the user is pushed to the inner view and open the menu then it automatically poped to root view and then pushed it to the profile view. I am expecting it to push from the inner view itself.

I followed [this tutorial](https://blckbirds.com/post/side-menu-hamburger-menu-in-swiftui/#:%7E:text=Welcome%20to%20a%20new%20SwiftUI,or%20addition%20to%20tab%20bars.) to create a navigation side menu.

[image: Navigation Link Issue]

Here is my code. I have created this navigation model `AppNavigationViewModel` which I have passed to inner views for easy access as there can be n number of inners views.

```
class AppNavigationViewModel:ObservableObject {
    @Published var shouldPushToContentView:Bool = false
    @Published var showMenu:Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var navigationModel:AppNavigationViewModel = AppNavigationViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                NavigationView {
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: ProfileView(),
                            isActive: self.$navigationModel.shouldPushToContentView,
                            label: {
                                EmptyView()
                            })
                        MainView()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    }
                }
                if self.navigationModel.showMenu {
                    MenuView()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/2)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                }
            }
        }.environmentObject(self.navigationModel)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var navigationModel:AppNavigationViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: InnerMainView(),
            label: {
                Text("Push to subview")
            }
        )
        .navigationBarTitle("Root Menu", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: (
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.navigationModel.showMenu.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                    .imageScale(.large)
            }
        ))
    }
}

struct MenuView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var navigationModel:AppNavigationViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Button(action: {
                self.navigationModel.showMenu = false
                self.navigationModel.shouldPushToContentView = true
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Profile")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
            })
            .padding(.top, 100)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255).opacity(0.9))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct InnerMainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var navigationModel:AppNavigationViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                self.navigationModel.showMenu.toggle()
            }
        }) {
            Text("Show Menu From Inner Main View")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Inner View", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: (
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.navigationModel.showMenu.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                    .imageScale(.large)
            }
        ))
    }
}

struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var navigationModel:AppNavigationViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                self.navigationModel.showMenu.toggle()
            }
        }) {
            Text("Profile View")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Profile View", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: (
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.navigationModel.showMenu.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                    .imageScale(.large)
            }
        ))
    }
}
```

Comment: which device and OS are you using expect close animation else works fine with iOS 14.3

Comment: for close animation set zindex to menu view: ```if self.navigationModel.showMenu {
                    MenuView()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/2)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                        .zIndex(1) //<--- Here
                }```

Comment: @RajaKishan have you notice in the gif how on the opening of side menu inner view poped.

Comment: yes not able to reprodue.

Comment: Can you share your code here once as an answer?

Comment: I am using Xcode 12.5

Comment: Tested in 12.3.  just try to set .zIndex(1) as above in menu view.

Comment: with zIndex animation is fixed but not the navigation issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232996/discussion-between-malav-soni-and-raja-kishan).